# Intel 32bit protected mode enabling paging causes triple fault

Tags: x86, kernel, paging, intel, protected-mode

I am working on a hobbyist OS and I am having trouble with identity mapping and enabling paging. I am working with Bochs emulator, and I have the following error message :=

00691299602e[CPU0 ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x0e)

00691299602e[CPU0 ] interrupt(): gate descriptor is not valid sys seg (vector=0x08)

00691299602i[CPU0 ] CPU is in protected mode (active)

00691299602i[CPU0 ] CS.d_b = 32 bit

00691299602i[CPU0 ] SS.d_b = 32 bit

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | EAX=e0000011  EBX=00000209  ECX=00000f9f  EDX=00000f9f

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | ESP=0000ff5c  EBP=00000001  ESI=00000209  EDI=0001d000

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | IOPL=0 id vip vif ac vm RF nt of df if tf SF zf af PF cf

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | SEG selector     base    limit G D

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D

00691299602i[CPU0 ] |  CS:0008( 0001| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1

00691299602i[CPU0 ] |  DS:0018( 0003| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1

00691299602i[CPU0 ] |  SS:0018( 0003| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1

00691299602i[CPU0 ] |  ES:0018( 0003| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1

00691299602i[CPU0 ] |  FS:0018( 0003| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1

00691299602i[CPU0 ] |  GS:0018( 0003| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | EIP=00102764 (00102764)

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | CR0=0xe0000011 CR2=0xe0000011

00691299602i[CPU0 ] | CR3=0x00014000 CR4=0x00000000

00691299602i[CPU0 ] 0x00102764>> add byte ptr ds:[eax], al : 0000

00691299602e[CPU0 ] exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 
00h, resetting

What I am trying to do is identity map the entire available ram, and the code I am using 
to do this is :=

```
printk(" page_limit [%d]\n",page_limit);
for(i=0,virt=0; i < NR_PAGES; ++i,virt += PAGE_SIZE) {
    frame = (PAGE_SIZE * (i % 1024));
    if(i < page_limit) {
        page = 0;
        PT_SET_ATTRIB(page, PTE_PRESENT);
        PT_SET_ATTRIB(page, PTE_READ_WRITE);
        PT_SET_FRAME(page, frame);
        KERNEL_PAGE_TABLE[i] = page;
    } else {
        page = 0;
        PT_SET_ATTRIB(page, PTE_PRESENT);
        PT_SET_ATTRIB(page, PTE_READ_WRITE);
        PT_SET_ATTRIB(page, PTE_USER);
        PT_SET_FRAME(page, frame);
        KERNEL_PAGE_TABLE[i] = page;
    }
}

printk(" page_limit [%d]\n",page_limit);
for(i = 0, frame = (unsigned)KERNEL_PAGE_TABLE; 
        i < NR_PAGE_TABLES; ++i, frame += PAGE_SIZE) {
    if(i < page_limit) {
        page = 0;
        PD_SET_ATTRIB(page, PDE_PRESENT);
        PD_SET_ATTRIB(page, PDE_READ_WRITE);
        PD_SET_FRAME(page, frame);
        KERNEL_PAGE_DIR[i] = page;
    } else {
        page = 0;
        PD_SET_ATTRIB(page, PDE_PRESENT);
        PD_SET_ATTRIB(page, PDE_READ_WRITE);
        PD_SET_ATTRIB(page, PDE_USER);
        PD_SET_FRAME(page, frame);
        KERNEL_PAGE_DIR[i] = page;
    }
}

Where the following macros are defined :=

#define PD_SET_ATTRIB(entry, attrib) \
    (entry) |= (attrib);

#define PD_SET_FRAME(entry, addr) \
    (entry) = ((entry) & ~0xFFFFF000) | (addr << 12);
```

And similar for PT_SET_ATTRIB and PT_SET_FRAME. I think the mapping is wrong,
the actual line Bochs stops on looks like its referencing a null pointer :=

```
add byte ptr ds:[eax], al : 0000
```

but it also looks like the CPU tried to load the page fault and double fault handlers
and eventually triple faulted causing a CPU reset. I am hoping someone could help
point out the error.

Thanks

Comment: And are you in user mode?

Comment: Minimal working paging example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/24988411adf10cf9f6afd1566e35472eb8ae771a/paging.S